# jQuery periodical update : how to check whether content fetched is different from old content fetched

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am trying to implement an [ajax.periodicalUpdater](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/) like that of Prototypejs but with jQuery. My aim is that as soon as the page loads, it will load the content of any url I would have placed in parameter.

Now if the content fetched after an interval of second is the same as the one fetched previously, I would like to increase the delay for the next check in order to reduce server load.

This is what I did

```
     <div id="div_a_updater" class="div_a_updater">Mettre ici</div> 
 
<script>
 
function mettreajour_periodique(span_id, url_traitement, nos_parametres, our_frequency, our_decay, our_decay_to_reset)
{
 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
jQuery("#"+span_id).load(url_traitement);
    
setInterval(function(){
jQuery("#"+span_id).load(url_traitement)
}, our_frequency);
    
});
 
    
}
 

mettreajour_periodique('div_a_updater', 'brouillons_touse.php', '&membre=', 15000, 2000, 3600);

</script>
```

How to check whether content fetched is different from old content fetched and increase the delay if the content fetched it the same as old content fetched ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [how this is implemented in Prototype](https://github.com/prototypejs/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/ajax/periodical_updater.js#L249). In broad steps:

1. decay defaults to 1 (no effect on interval), but can be assigned a value greater than 1.
2. endpoint is requested and the response is assigned to a variable.
3. response is compared to previous response (if available). If they are the same, decay is multiplied by itself and assigned back to itself (exponential growth). If they are different, then set decay back to its original value
4. next request is scheduled as interval*decay
5. previous response value is updated with the latest response value
6. element on screen is updated with response value
7. go to 2

The key takeaway here is that you don't want to use `setInterval` to schedule this, but rather `setTimeout`, since that allows you to get a new value for the delay between requests each time.

Comment: Pratically based on my code, can you please tell me what I have to edit to get it done ?